# Using apache simple regression

Tags: java, android, linear-regression, apache-commons-math

I have an application that uses linear regression. I downloaded `common math` apache library where there is a class `SimpleRegression`.

I read the documentation but i didn't understand it very well.

Here is what i want to do:
Every 200ms i am going to enter a data set with `counter` as Y and `value` as X.

Every 1s ( so 5 data entries ) i want to check the regression and see if some value Z is on the line or not.

Data entry part i know how to do, but i am not sure how to check if some value iz on the line, or not.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: if the line has slope `a` and `b` for y-intercept , the point `(u, v)` is on the line if and only if `v = a*u + b`, is that what you ask? See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression

Comment: Probably something similar. I will try it like that.

Comment: Thanks this could work!

Comment: yes maths usually "could" work ;)

Comment: yes, but i said this could work, because i looked at the documentation and i actually saw what i could do to replicate your formula :D